# New Sql query solution

Tags: sql

```
person_id | manager_id | name |
          |            |      |
-------------------------------
```

I have to display name of every person with manager name.

Yes its complete table. Thats all I have.

Comment: Is this the complete table? Is it self referencing?

Comment: +1 because I am happy to see such a nice, short, clear question on SOF

Comment: -1 for asking TWICE in 5 minutes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126728/sql-query-for-this

Comment: @Adam Matan: This is not a duplicate, it refers to the same table but asks for a different result.

Comment: For those that are interested: Table name = person, database = MySQL. (Found from previous thread)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one should give you all employees that have a manager, with `employee_name` and `manager_name`. Replace `your_table` by your table name.

If you want to get all persons, also that without manager, replace the `JOIN` by a `LEFT JOIN`. This would return `NULL` as `manager_name` for all persons without `manager_id`.

```
SELECT t1.name employee_name, t2.name manager_name
FROM [your_table] t1
JOIN [your_table] t2 ON ( t1.manager_id = t2.person_id )
```

Answer (score 4):

Which SQL dialect? Here's some TSQL, but I'm vague to the actual question ("every person with manager name"); if you mean "given a manager name, list the people (reports)", then:

```
SELECT peon.[person_id], peon.[name]
FROM [thetable] mgr
INNER JOIN [thetable] peon
  ON peon.manager_id = mgr.[person_id]
WHERE mgr.[name] = @name
ORDER BY peon.[name]
```

If you mean "list the people, along with their manager's name", then:

```
SELECT peon.[person_id], peon.[name], mgr.[name] AS [manager]
FROM [thetable] peon
LEFT OUTER JOIN [thetable] mgr
  ON mgr.[person_id] = peon.manager_id
ORDER BY peon.[name]
```

Comment: No, it should be `mrg` not `mgr` because this is TQSL, not T-SQL. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT person.name, manager.name 
FROM table person, table manager 
WHERE person.manager_id = manager.person_id
```

Comment: @gbn: It is called *implicit join notation* not "old style JOIN". Is it forbidden to use it? Or why is it bad?

Comment: It was replaced in ANSI 92 by explicit JOIN. Also, that outer join syntax is being removed in SQL Server 2008 R2. Finally, and more practically, it mixes up filters and joins, and makes it easy to end up with partial cross joins. if you can find any references that suggest using this syntax over explicit JOIN, feel free to share them. @Ankit: So what. It's bad practice.