# What is the SQL query for finding the name of manager who supervises maximum number of employees?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
person_id | manager_id | name |
          |            |      |
-------------------------------
```

Query to find name of manager who supervises maximum number of employees?

**Added:** This is the only table. Yes self-referencing. DB is mysql. Recursive queries will also do.

Comment: Do you want a recursive query?

Comment: still none of the answers work!!!

Comment: What is the name of your table?

Comment: Ankit: Perhaps if you answered the clarifying questions, more people would be interested in answering your question?!

Comment: PS: thanks for tagging your question with mysql, but you still need to answer whether you want to include the entire tree of employees under a manager or only the first level. This makes a huge difference to how the answer will be.

Comment: What do you want the result to be if there are two managers with an equal maximum? Return both, or just one? If the latter, which one? Any one?

Comment: Recursive query will do. DB is mysql. Table name is person (does it matter?) Ideally both should be returned, but I am still to get an answer that works for just one.

Comment: What do you mean by 'recursive queries will also do'? Does this mean that non-recursive queries are wrong? The two queries will give different answers. They can't both be right. Please can you give some example data and the expected output for that data?

Comment: @Ankit: Yes, the table name matters. We have to write it when we submit our answers. If we write the wrong table name, and you make an error with replacing it with the correct name (for example if you don't notice that there are two places where it needs to be changed) it will cause unnecessary errors and we will waste a lot of time debugging it. If you tell us the table name, we can test our query exactly as it would be in your system, and so there is less chance of errors creeping in. Also if your table name is a reserved word, this could also cause strange errors.

Comment: @Mark thanks!

Ideally I would have preferred a non-recursive query, but since i am not getting solutions, i am desperate.

Comment: A recursive query is more difficult. I have already submitted an answer about half-an-hour ago using a non-recusive query. Have you even looked at it yet? There is little point in me answering your questions if you don't even look at my answers. There is no reason to be desperate. Describe your question more clearly and more accurately. The quality of the answers depend on the quality of the question.

Comment: yes i looked at your solution almost as soon as you posted it. Marked it as right answers as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you want, so if this isn't what you want please clarify your question.

This query returns just one of the managers if there is a tie:

```
SELECT T2.name FROM (
    SELECT manager_id
    FROM table1
    WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY manager_id
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS T1
JOIN table1 AS T2
ON T1.manager_id = T2.person_id
```

Result of query:

```
Bar
```

Here's a query that fetches all managers with the tied maximum count in the case that there is a tie:

```
SELECT name FROM (
    SELECT manager_id, COUNT(*) AS C
    FROM person
    WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY manager_id) AS Counts
JOIN (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS C
    FROM person
    WHERE manager_id IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY manager_id
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
    LIMIT 1
) AS MaxCount
ON Counts.C = MaxCount.C
JOIN person
ON Counts.manager_id = person.person_id
```

Result of the second query:

```
Foo
Bar
```

Here's my test data:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (person_id int NOT NULL, manager_id nvarchar(100) NULL, name nvarchar(100) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO Table1 (person_id, manager_id, name) VALUES
(1, NULL, 'Foo'),
(2, '1', 'Bar'),
(3, '1', 'Baz'),
(4, '2', 'Qux'),
(5, '2', 'Quux'),
(6, '3', 'Corge');
```

Comment: You're welcome. It took me a long time to figure out exactly what you wanted. Thanks for being patient with my constant questions. :) Next time you post a similar question, I'll probably ask you very similar questions, so it would be a good idea to put the answers in your question from the start.

Answer (score 5):

This query returns the `manager_id` and `manager_name` of the manager with the maximal number of employees.

The trick is in the `HAVING` clause, which allows aggregates and counts over multiple rows.

```
SELECT manager_id,name, count(*) 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY manager_id, name
    HAVING max(count(*));
```

You can read more in the short but informative [w3schools.com `HAVING clause` tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_having.asp).

If the manager_id references a person id in the same table, [Svinto's answer might be more suitable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2126728/sql-query-for-this/2126737#2126737).

Comment: +1 This is smarter than the question, as it allows for a tie.

Comment: You have to change that also in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Felix thanks, corrected - TOO LITTLE SLEEP, TOO LITTLE COFFEE.

Comment: SQL Error - Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT name 
FROM table 
WHERE person_id = (
    SELECT manager_id 
    FROM table 
    GROUP BY manager_id 
    HAVING max(count(*)))
```

Comment: +1 ...and this one noticed that we need the name, not the id, but it doesn't allow for a tie.

Comment: Unknown column 'count' in 'having clause'

Comment: +1 for noticing self reference; I think it should be `HAVING max(count(*))

Comment: Should be max(count(*)). Still doesn't allow for a tie, however.

Comment: SQL Error - Invalid use of group function

Answer (score 1):

Assuming manager_id have a reference to person_id and name of table: table_name

```
SELECT name FROM (
  SELECT manager_id
  FROM table_name
  GROUP BY manager_id
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
) t
INNER JOIN table_name ON t.manager_id = table_name.person_id
```

**edit:**
Removed HAVING MAX COUNT, added ORDER BY COUNT DESC LIMIT 1 in subquery

Comment: Sorry but this still doesn't work for `(1, NULL, 'Foo'),(2, NULL, 'Bar'), (3, 1, 'Baz')` as it returns no rows instead of FOO. Sorry for picking on your answer in particular - everyone else here has made the same mistake too. I chose yours because it had no comments and others have more serious errors too that have already been pointed out. See my answer for a working version.